# React Sematic-UI Dropdown renderLabel popup / tooltip on mouse hover

Tags: reactjs, popup, label, dropdown

I'm making a react Sematic-UI Dropdown with multiselect and custom renderLabel function, I want to add tooltip / popup to these labels which show additional details of the item that the label represents. I have some rough idea how I might be able to do this, but I'm asking here first if someone has already done this or something similar and wants to share the knowledge.

http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/
[image: Picture of renderLabel function on react sematic-ui website]

currently I have this code:

```
renderLabel = (label) => {
return({
    color: 'teal',
    content: `${label.value}`,
    icon: 'user'
})}
```

and it looks like:
[image]

I imagine I would need to do something like:

```
renderLabel = (label) => {
return({
    color: 'teal',
    content: `${label.value}`,
    icon: 'user'
    description: 'this is tooltip text...'
})}
```

and make an oldschool css tooltip of the description prop, something like:

```
[description] {position: -ms-device-fixed;}

[description]:before {
    content:'';
    /* hides the tooltip when not hovered */
    display:none;
    content:'';
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:35px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    width: .71428571em;
    height: .71428571em;}

[description]:after {
    display:none;
    content:attr(description);
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    left:0px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    z-index:9;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4285em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    word-wrap:normal;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;}

[description]:hover:before,[description]:hover:after {
            display:block;}
```

but this is unpractical and hard coded, sematic-ui has [popup](http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/) module already in it, but I can't figure how to implement that here.

Answer (score 1):

```
renderLabel={(a, b, c) => {
                return (
                  <Popup
                    content={<div>Whatever i want here</div>}
                    eventsEnabled={true}
                    on="click"
                    onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                    onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
                    open={open}
                    trigger={<Label content={a.text} {...c} />}
                  />
                );
              }}
```

You will need to improve setOpen method to just open the popop you want to be opened, maybe passing some id